# How do I combine projection and selection operators in relational algebra here?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I have this query in SQL finding two columns in a table where a certain condition is met, but I have to convert this query into relational algebra.

I have to select a name and an address from a table (People) where the person is older than 18:

```sql
select name, address from People where age>18
```

... which would translate to:

```
π name,address σ age>18 (People)
```

Is this correct?

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. In the programming language consisting of nested calls of some relational algebra, an expression that is a base name denotes the current relation value assigned to the base & another expression denotes the relation value of calling its operator with the relation values of its arguments. But until you give your syntax this can't be answered.

Answer (score 2):

```
R1 := σ age>18 (People)
R2 := π name,address(R1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
π name, address (σ age>18 (People))
```